# Find the general solution of the given second order differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the given second order differential equation. $$4y''+y'=0$$
This was my procedure to solving this problem:
$\chi(r)=4r^2+r=0$
$r(4r+1)=0$
$r=0, -\frac14$
$y_1=e^{0x}, y_2=e^{-\frac14x}$
And this led to get the answer,
$y=C_1+C_2e^{-\frac14x}$
I don't really have a question unless I solved this problem incorrectly. If someone could kindly check over my work to see if I did it right, that would be great!

Comment: Should one of the variables by $y$ or $y''$?  Right now it is first order, with solution any linear function as $y'=0$

Comment: You are missing $y''$. I believe it is $4y''$.

Comment: You can use Wolfram Alpha to check that your answer is right. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+4y''%2By'%3D0&t=sftb01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fine for the general solution, assuming the first term is $4y''$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint** you can reduce the order by putting

> $$y'=w$$